# Can't not get JSON file cross domain

Tags: php, jquery, json

I generate a list of objects in a json file using PHP and then i used jQuery to get data from it

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "get",
        dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (data) {
                for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = data[i].Kategorianimi;

    }
    }).fail(function () {
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = "cant get json";
    })

});
```

It worked ok in localhost but when i give a external host link to the url, it not work. Is there anyone has same issue with me and could you guy show me how to fix it? thanks.

When i add a header like this, then my JSON data was error

```
<?php
require_once "../pdo/kategoriaPDO.php";
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *’);

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: dinhthinh
 * Date: 27/11/16
 * Time: 14:07
 */
$katepdo = new KatePDO();
$json = str_replace("\u0000","",json_encode($katepdo->listaKaikkiKategoriat(), true));
echo stripcslashes($json);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add your host to server's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, or just send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header from server

Comment: Can i add it from client side using javascript bro? Because this host is my school and i dont have permission to modify the config file, thanks for quick supporting.

Comment: No, you can't :( Its of security reasons

Comment: header() must be strongly after <?php. Try this: `<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *’);
require_once "../pdo/kategoriaPDO.php";`

Comment: I only got a blank page with my json file when i write the header into PHP file. without errors. But when i remove it, the data appear again, it's so difficult to understand.

Comment: lol. look your quotes (closing one). fixed: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Comment: Marking my answer as "right one" will be best reward :P

Comment: Sr maybe i did something wrong, can u guide me how to do it?

Comment: U did it. Thanx a lot. Have a nice day :D

Comment: Yes, you two bro!

Answer (score 2):

The error You might be getting is that

> No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requeswted resource. localhost:8080 is thus not allowed Access.

This happens because browsers send a preflight `OPTIONS` requested to the server to see if it has access before sending the actual request

For security reasons, browsers restrict `cross-origin HTTP requests` initiated from within scripts. For example, `XMLHttpRequest` and `Fetch` follow the same-origin policy. So, a web application using `XMLHttpRequest or Fetch` could only make HTTP requests to its `own domain`. To improve web applications, developers asked browser vendors to allow `cross-domain` requests.

You server must then allow this by specifying the `Access-Control-Allow-Orgin` for `localhost`

Or for testing purpose you can use the `CORS plugin for Chrome extension` and test you code. But anyways later you need to enable CORS from the server.

Read more about cors **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)**

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: It didn't show data again, maybe array is empty. I have blank page.

Comment: You can do console.log In the done() and fail() functions and see what you are getting

Comment: Cannot do it bro, cause console.log doesn't support XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: What I meant you to do is `done(function (data) { console.log(data);
                for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = data[i].Kategorianimi;

    }`

Comment: it not print anything in console window bro, because always when i run it as js file, it show me that js doesnt support XMLHttpRequest. It only work when we run in browser. But when i run it, i got a warning text that i put it in a fail condition, that can't get json.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/node /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/nailsvaraus/js/test.js
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/nailsvaraus/js/test.js:3
    $.ajax({
    ^

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/nailsvaraus/js/test.js:3:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3

Comment: It looks like you are getting $ is not defined. meaning that you need to import jquery because ussing ajax call, but I still cant understand then how are you getting anything in the browser that you have logged in the fail method

Comment: This is warning from my console window. As i said before, cann't run ajax inside js console. Ofcourse i already import jquery in html file.